# How can I use pip cache in github actions?

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions

I am having some issues with using cached pip in Github Actions. My workflow setup is

```
name: tests

on: [push, pull_request]

jobs:
  linux:

    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    strategy:
      max-parallel: 4
      matrix:
        python-version: [3.6, 3.7, 3.8]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Set up Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-python@v1
      with:
        python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
    - uses: actions/cache@v1
      with:
        path: ~/.cache/pip
        key: ${{ runner.os }}-pip-${{ hashFiles('**/requirements.txt') }}
        restore-keys: |
          ${{ runner.os }}-pip-
    - name: Install
      if: steps.cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
      run: |
        pip install pytest pytest-cov bandit sphinx recommonmark
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install .
    - name: Test with pytest
      run: |
        pytest --disable-pytest-warnings --cov-report=xml --cov=chepy --cov-config=.coveragerc tests/
        coverage report -m
    - name: Test with bandit
      run: |
        bandit --recursive chepy/ --ignore-nosec --skip B101,B413,B303,B310,B112,B304,B320,B410,B404
    - name: Test docs
      run: |
        make -C docs/ clean html
    - name: Upload to codecov
      uses: codecov/codecov-action@v1.0.3
      with:
        token: ${{secrets.CODECOV_TOKEN}}
        file: ./coverage.xml
```

The issue I am having is that in subsequent actions that are triggered, it will not using the cache, but instead installing from pip all over again.

How can I make it use the cache?

Comment: I would also make the cache depend on the python version in general, since some python packages the result of pip install depends on the python version

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You forgot about adding `id` in step which uses `actions/cache`. This is required for condition in `Install` step to work.

```
- uses: actions/cache@v1
  id:   cache
  with:
   ...
```

Answer (score 27):

You can also cache a virtualenv, like this:

```
    - uses: actions/cache@v2
      id: cache-venv  # name for referring later
      with:
        path: ./.venv/  # what we cache: the virtualenv
        # The cache key depends on requirements.txt
        key: ${{ runner.os }}-venv-${{ hashFiles('**/requirements*.txt') }}
        restore-keys: |
          ${{ runner.os }}-venv-
    # Build a virtualenv, but only if it doesn't already exist
    - run: python -m venv ./.venv && . ./.venv/bin/activate && 
           pip install -r requirements.txt
      if: steps.cache-venv.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
    # Run tests
    # Note that you have to activate the virtualenv in every step
    # because GitHub actions doesn't preserve the environment
    - run: . ./.venv/bin/activate && nosetests tests/
```

Comment: The use of restore-keys, in this case, is unneeded (actually incorrect, though it won't have any effect). See: ["What is the logic in using the restore-keys field in the GitHub cache action?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74401969/14354604). I've proposed an edit for this.

Answer (score 5):

I encountered a similar issue when implementing caching for [Rikai](https://github.com/eto-ai/rikai/blob/358fef8888118f13215a0888c280b233fd7ce6bf/.github/workflows/python.yml#L42-L48) project.

Finally, I found the reason why it will not work as I expected if I just follow the example in the doc of [github actions cache](https://github.com/actions/cache/blob/main/examples.md#python---pip)

Every `pip install` execution actually takes two steps.

1. To download the pip package.
2. To run the install script.

These years internet speed increased a lot. So today, the second step might take more time than the first one, especially when the second step contains complex behaviors like compiling a `C/C++` project. But `~/.cache/pip` only caches downloaded packages, not installed packages. Downloading cached packages(from `Github`) also needs time, maybe not so different from downloading from `PyPI`. So you do not have an evident feeling about the cache.

Now there is my solution. That's caching the installed packages, not the downloaded packages. To know where is the installed packages, run `pip install` again, you will see something like

```
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.1.0 in /.../site-packages (from scikit-learn->rikai==0.0.19.dev0) (1.7.3)
```

The `/.../site-packages` is where your packages are finally installed. That directory differs by environment so you have to try by yourself to know it.

After I tried the new directory, I found it really works, every install command shows a log

```
Requirement already satisfied: xxx>=xx in xxx/site-packages (from xxx)
```

### One more thing

The default `site-packages` directory also contains the standard library of the Python interpreter, actually you don't need to cache it, because it's included by `actions/setup-python`. The best way I can find is to install packages into the user namespace, by `pip install --user`, and to cache the user's `site-packages` directory. If you are not sure where it is, you can use the environment variable `PYTHONUSERBASE`.

Then you can cache the necessary packages in a very efficient way.

A full workable example is in [this file](https://github.com/eto-ai/rikai/blob/358fef8888118f13215a0888c280b233fd7ce6bf/.github/workflows/python.yml)

Answer (score 5):

It appears `actions/setup-python@v4` comes with a built-in cache feature.

```
steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
- uses: actions/setup-python@v4
  with:
    python-version: '3.9'
    cache: 'pip' # caching pip dependencies
- run: pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Refer this page for more details:
https://github.com/actions/setup-python#caching-packages-dependencies

Answer (score 2):

If you are using multiple OSes, you can do the following to obtain the pip cache in a matrix:

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    strategy:
      matrix:
        os: [ubuntu-latest, macos-latest, windows-latest]
        include:
        - os: ubuntu-latest
          path: ~/.cache/pip
        - os: macos-latest
          path: ~/Library/Caches/pip
        - os: windows-latest
          path: ~\AppData\Local\pip\Cache
    steps:
    - uses: actions/cache@v2
      with:
        path: ${{ matrix.path }}
        key: ${{ runner.os }}-pip-${{ hashFiles('**/requirements.txt') }}
        restore-keys: ${{ runner.os }}-pip-
```

***As of pip 20.1+***, you can also use `pip` to automatically obtain the cache directory in your matrix:

```
- name: Get pip cache dir
  id: pip-cache
  run: |
    echo "::set-output name=dir::$(pip cache dir)"

- name: pip cache
  uses: actions/cache@v2
  with:
    path: ${{ steps.pip-cache.outputs.dir }}
    key: ${{ runner.os }}-pip-${{ hashFiles('**/requirements.txt') }}
    restore-keys: |
      ${{ runner.os }}-pip-
```

Source: https://github.com/actions/cache/blob/main/examples.md#python---pip

Answer (score 0):

```
...
      - name: set PIP_CACHE
        shell: python
        run: |
          import os
          import platform
          from os.path import expanduser

          home = expanduser("~")
          cache_path = {
            "Linux": f"{home}/.cache/pip",
            "Darwin": f"{home}Library/Caches/pip",
            "Windows": f"{home}\\AppData\\Local\\pip\\Cache"
          }[platform.system()]

          os.system(f"echo PIP_CACHE={cache_path} >> {os.environ['GITHUB_ENV']}")

      - uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: ${{ env.PIP_CACHE }}
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-pip-${{ hashFiles('**/requirements.txt') }}
          restore-keys: ${{ runner.os }}-pip-
...
```